# Function stops if first parameter (an array) has 20-25 keys

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, arrays

`<EDIT>`

**The issue was related to passing arrays via GET and hitting the URL length limits in some AJAX code. I solved the issue by switching to the POST method.**

`</EDIT>`

I have a class I'm using at work to batch reassign leads in a SugarCRM database.

Everything works perfectly in the class except for this one function:

```
function reassign($leads = null, $newAssigned = null, $oldAssigned = null)
{
    // How many professionals to assign to?
    $roundrobin = count($newAssigned) - 1;
    $recurse = 0;

    if (!isset($leads)) {
        die("You must select the accounts to reassign!");
    }
    if (!isset($newAssigned)) {
        die("You must select a Professional!");
    }
    if (!isset($oldAssigned)) {
        die("Something broke in the Assigning process. Check javascript.");
    }

    try {
    foreach ($leads as $key => $value) {
        $sql_update = "UPDATE accounts SET assigned_user_id = '".$newAssigned[$recurse]."' WHERE id = '".$value."'";
        $assignment = $this->db_handle->prepare($sql_update);
        $assignment->execute();
        unset($assignment);

        $sql_statement = "INSERT INTO accounts_audit 
                            (id,
                            parent_id,
                            date_created,
                            created_by,
                            field_name,
                            data_type,
                            before_value_string,
                            after_value_string)
                        VALUES (uuid(),
                                '".$value."',
                                now(),
                                '".$_SESSION['session_user_id']."',
                                'assigned_user_id',
                                'relate',
                                '".$oldAssigned[$key]."',
                                '".$newAssigned[$recurse]."')";

        $audit_statement = $this->db_handle->prepare($sql_statement);
        $audit_statement->execute();
        unset($audit_statement);

        if ($recurse < $roundrobin) {
            $recurse++;
        } else {
            $recurse = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    echo "Successful!\n";
}
```

This function allows the user to check off any number of leads from a generated list, and re-assign those leads to any number of reps in a list equally, and log those changes in a table for auditing purposes.

The problem I am having is that this function will seize up and hang if the user selects anywhere from 20-25 leads or so. Any less than 20 and it never hangs. This is an issue because the user must be able to re-assign hundreds or potentially thousands of leads.

Any idea as to why it would lock up (the number of leads that it locks up with varies, usually 20-25) like this? The change is immediate when it's under 20 leads.

EDIT:

Updated the code to show statement closes. Still no changes in behaviour. When the number of leads are selected that causes it to break, no changes are made. It does not do the first 19-20 and stop on the rest, no changes get made and nothing is added to the audit table. Less than the breaking point and all changes are done and logged in the audit table.

I'm using PDO to connect to the db:

```
try {
    $this->db_handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbHost;dbname=$this->dbDatabase", $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
    $this->db_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

And I get no errors there. I also do not get any errors in the log for any of the code. I am so confused.

EDIT #2:

As per the suggestion, here's the same with bound parameters...

```
function reassign($leads = null, $newAssigned = null, $oldAssigned = null)
{
    // How many professionals to assign to?
    $roundrobin = count($newAssigned) - 1;
    $recurse = 0;

    $sql_assign = "UPDATE accounts SET assigned_user_id = :new_user_id WHERE id = :account_id";
    $sql_audit  = "INSERT INTO accounts_audit
                            (id,
                            parent_id,
                            date_created,
                            created_by,
                            field_name,
                            data_type,
                            before_value_string,
                            after_value_string)
                        VALUES (uuid(),
                                :parent_id,
                                now(),
                                :created_by,
                                'assigned_user_id',
                                'relate',
                                :old_assigned_user,
                                :new_assigned_user)";

    $assignment = $this->db_handle->prepare($sql_assign);
    $audit      = $this->db_handle->prepare($sql_audit);

    if (!isset($leads)) {
        die("You must select the accounts to reassign!");
    }
    if (!isset($newAssigned)) {
        die("You must select a Professional!");
    }
    if (!isset($oldAssigned)) {
        die("Something broke in the Assigning process. Check javascript.");
    }

    try {
    foreach ($leads as $key => $value) {
        $assign_params = array(':new_user_id' => $newAssigned[$recurse], ':account_id' => $value);
        $assignment->execute($assign_params);

        $audit_params = array(':parent_id' => $value, ':created_by' => $_SESSION['session_user_id'], ':old_assigned_user' => $oldAssigned[$key], ':new_assigned_user' => $newAssigned[$recurse]);
        $audit->execute($audit_params);

        if ($recurse < $roundrobin) {
            $recurse++;
        } else {
            $recurse = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    echo "Successful!\n";
}
```

No difference, other than being faster when it DOES work. :(

Comment: and I would love to see error handling (maybe giving a hint already what is wrong ) ;-) and not only "echo sucessfull"

Comment: what does _locks up_ mean? do the first 20 changes make it to the database and it stops executing then? does it throw errors? have you silenced some sort of errors or notices? does your db_handle throw exceptions?

Comment: do you tracked execution times? does the database have high load and locking issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying cause to the problems I was experiencing were not due to leaking prepared statements, as suggested by Paul Dixon, although he did offer excellent advice on preventing that from occurring.

This script was called via AJAX using the GET method. The script broke after the arrays in param1 and param2 reached a certain length. This was occurring because the URL was exceeding the maximum length limit, and not because of the PHP script itself.

Once I switched from the GET method in my AJAX to the PST method, the issues I was experiencing immediately went away.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're leaking prepared statements. Your error log might have clues.

As you are using prepared statements, why not prepare them outside the loop, and execute them with parameters inside the loop? I'm assuming you're using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) here, in which case you'll need to use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Then you'll only every create 2 prepared statements!

```
//example prepare
$assignUser= $this->db_handle->prepare(
    "UPDATE accounts ".
    "SET assigned_user_id=? ".
    "WHERE id=?");


while (...)
{
    //example bind + execute
    $assignUser->bind_param("ii", $newAssigned[$recurse], $value);
    $assignUser->execute();


}
```

Comment: Binding the parameters makes no difference (see EDIT #2), other than being faster when it DOES work. Also, I'm using PDO, not mysqli.